# Как перевести римское число в арабское?

Tags: c#

> Дан текст из заглавных латинских букв и если текст является числом римским, то перевести его в арабское.

```
string text = "";
char[] ROMAN = { 'M', 'D', 'C', 'L', 'X', 'V', 'I' };

char[] mas = new char[text.Length];
Int16[]Arab = {
1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1};

Console.Write("Введите строку заглавных латинских  букв:n ");
text = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Переведенные числа:");
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    if (text[i] == ROMAN[j]) {
        mas[i] = Convert.ToChar(Arab[j]);

    } else
        break;
    }
}

int g = 0, u = 0;
// В этом блоке надо, чтоб был алгоритм перевода чисел из римских в арабские
for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++)   
{
}

Console.WriteLine(g);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: как бы пусть будет, как ответ на ваш вопрос: [RomanNumeralExtensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/291402/735536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну сразу же. Вы инициализируете переменную `mas` до того, как вводится `text`. В результате массив будет получаться нулевой длины, и обращение к нему по любому индексу приведёт к ошибке.

Далее. В зависимости от уже встретившихся символов, множество допустимых следующих символов уменьшается.

Например, символ C может означать как 100, так и -100 (CM, CD). Но если более одного символа C подряд, то это может быть только 100. После этой группы может встречаться только L, X, V и I.

Comment: Я это понимаю, я в коде не могу выразить!

Answer (score 0):

Так, как по мне, лучше

```
private static Dictionary<char, int> map = new Dictionary<char, int>()
    {
        {'I', 1 },
        {'V', 5 },
        {'X', 10 },
        {'L', 50 },
        {'C', 100 },
        {'D', 500 },
        {'M', 1000 }
    };
    public static int Parse(string roman)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<roman.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i+1 < roman.Length && IsSubtractive(roman[i], roman[i+1]))
            {
                result -= map[roman[i]];
            }
            else
            {
                result += map[roman[i]];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static bool IsSubtractive(char c1, char c2)
    {
        return map[c1]  < map[c2];
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int arabicNumber;
        Console.Write("Enter roman number: ");
        string roman=Console.ReadLine();
        arabicNumber = Parse(roman);
        Console.WriteLine("Arabic number - " + arabicNumber);
        

    }
```

Comment: Может еще актуально)